# Let’s choose a definite name for our favourite molecule, in case he gets elected as a mod!

Tags: discussion

[We all know this guy who nominated themself for a moderator position in the upcoming election](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/election/2#post-60198).<sup>[1]</sup> Over the course of [history-of-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-chemistry), we got to know him under a number of different names.<sup>[2]</sup>

Notice the comments under his nomination post over at the election site. Of if you’re too lazy to follow the link, here are the important ones:

> If we vote for you, can we choose your new name on meta? ;) – Jan Oct 3 at 21:29
>
> @Jan I've decided I'll keep one name if I ever become a mod on any site. So OK. – Rubisco Oct 4 at 14:54

Since the actual election will happen soon, it is *vital* we start proposing names<sup>[3]</sup> — and this is the thread to do this!

Add an answer suggesting a name for You-know-who. Vote on those you like and don’t vote on those you don’t like. Additionally, to make counting easier, please only add *one* name per answer. All names should adhere to the be-nice policy and, of course, Rubisco has the right to veto a suggestion.

This closes when the election closes<sup>[4]</sup> and if Rubisco is not elected, the entire thing is moot.

---

**Notes:**

[1]: If you didn’t: welcome to meta! Make yourself a home!

[2]: Including, but not limited to MAR, MAR spelt with funny characters, Ina, TIPS, DEAD, RuBisCO, …

[3]: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32817285#32817285

[4]: Open to other suggestions, if you feel timeframe *x* be so much better.

Comment: I'd like to propose "MAR spelt with funny characters".

Comment: One downside to that though @Ortho. I used to be all Unicody until someone on meta.ELL complained that I'm not pingable on the mobile site.

Comment: @Rubisco No, I literally mean: "MAR spelt with funny characters". Eh, it's not a serious proposal, which is why I didn't post it as an answer ^^

Comment: @Ortho that . . . is the most beautiful words you ever uttered. I want it as an answer. NOW.

Comment: I'd like to close this primarily opinion based.

Comment: Even though I didn't make it, I will change my name to the one in the most upvoted answer. Oh that's right. IT'S MINE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since y'all like to play with my initials, what about just my initials?

I propose "MAR".

Comment: Somehow this sounds boring =C

Comment: @Jan mods are boring. (Don't tell anyone I said that)

Comment: Pffsh, your usernames are like ultra-secure passwords: you can't use the same one more than once.

Comment: @hBy2Py interestingly enough, "MAR" has never been my name. There has been some (one?) unicode name(s) which resembled MAR, but that doesn't count.

Comment: Pfah, @Rubisco skates free on a technicality!!

Comment: @M.A.R.ಠ_ಠ When did you insert the dots in your name? Changed from "MAR" to "M.A.R."?

Comment: @Gau just when I was about to change name.  If I were MAR, pinging me would have also pinged Mart.

Comment: @M.A.R.ಠ_ಠ ah true!

Answer (score 3):

Keeping with the chemical theme: **PolyMARthacrylate**

Comment: PolyMethAcRylate. ;)

Comment: I will read it like Poly-Martha-Crylate.

Comment: @pH13 -- Busting up your proposed names since 1888

Answer (score 3):

**Metal Argonide**

In case you didn’t immediately realise, the chemical abbreviation for that would be $\ce{MAr}$.

Answer (score 2):

The many named Mod

in analogy to the many faced god.

Answer (score 1):

Master MAR.

This is in reference and homage to Master Shake of Aqua Teen Hunger Force fame :)

Comment: "MAR", or "Master MAR"? The mastery bit is Yodaish

Comment: M$^{2}$, maybe?

Comment: Can we do that? It prolly gets ugly with Unicode.

Comment: How about MADerator?

Comment: Considering it.

Comment: Or MARderator. That gets it right.

Comment: *Marder* is the german name for a marten ... that sounds funny over here.

Comment: How about MARvelous?

Comment: Todd you have reached your name proposing limit. You can propose again in 23 hours.

Comment: @Todd We are no longer accepting name proposals from this account. See [the Help Center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) to learn more.

Comment: Yeah, I deserved that one...:)